# How to deliver a Web Library

Tags: web, javascript

I started to develop a library for web applications.

Now I see the problem when deliver the new application to the customer with the complete library, because the customer gets the whole library, but he didn't pay for.

I was not able to find a strategy in web development on the Internet to solve this.

My thought was to somehow strip the library on build time to the needed dependencies. But I dont know how.

What is best practice to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are developing some JS for the Web, you have to publish the source code of the library anyway, because that's the only thing the browser understands.

The only way to hide your code from a client is to publish a binary without the source. On the Web, client-side, this amounts to using either Java or ActiveX, which are both rather doomed endeavours nowadays. And Java is easily decompilable.

You can start by minifying your library, this will obfuscate the code a little.

You can also take this as a sign that you should split your library into components to deliver to your clients only what they need.

Comment: The last point of your answer is the strategy I would like to try. 

So far I see two ways to split the library. First split during development time. Which seems to be an very ugly way. Second to create a sublibrary during build time. The second is the nice way. This could probably be achieved with grunt. I have just no idea how and where to start.

The library needs to have some dependency management which is feasible to determine the needed parts on build. Or similar. Any ideas on this?

Or forget the second way and go the first?

Comment: Automatically surgeoning a Javascript library to keep only what will be used is a difficult problem to solve, since Javascript is a dynamic language. I am not aware of any existing program capable of doing this. OTOH, turning your library into a set of components would allow you to include needed components one by one, and then, at build time, concat-then-minify actually-used js scripts to deliver them to your client. This means inverting dependencies at every place in the code of your library where the set of components is known in whole. (e.g. switch case on widget type)